# Умная очистка старых архивов

Tags: linux

Добрый день. Нужна помощь в организации очистки каталога архивов сборок деплоя кода. Есть каталог `/var/www/archive` . В нем есть 4 сборки. Назовем их A B C D. Мне нужно чистить этот каталог от сборок больше 3х версий. То есть например есть сборки A.1.tar.gz, A.2.tar.gz, A3.tar.gz
Если сборки A B C обновляются часто то сборки D обновляются 1 раз в 3 месяца а то и реже. Как бы сделать умную чистку. Допустим проверять сколько есть версий сборок, если больше 3х тогда удалять самые старые, а последние 3 оставлять. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение которое нужно было мне.

```
#!/bin/bash
build="A_*.tar.gz"
build2="B_*.tar.gz"
build3="C_*.tar.gz"
build4="D_*.tar.gz"
dirb="/var/www/archive"

for project in $build $build2 $build3 $build4
do
count=`ls $dirb/$project | wc -l`
if [ $count -gt 3 ]; then
ls -1t $dirb/$project | sort -h -r | tail -n +4 | xargs rm
fi
done
```

Comment: в цикле можно просто написать ls -1t $dirb/$project |  tail -n +4 | xargs rm
эффект будет такой же, ключ  t сортирует по дате,  tail -n +4 - оставляет только последние 4 файла, поэтому $count считать не надо

Answer (score 3):

Сначала вам необходимо пролистить директорию, далее обработать список файлов в соответсвии с вашими условиями. Но есть более простой и универсальный способ, он хоть и выполняет `ls` несколько раз, но зато прост и надежен.

Листим с wildcard `*` нужные файлы и удаляем файлы если их больше трех. Можно повесить команды на разное время по крону, а лучше выполнять их после сборки.

```
ls -1t /var/www/archive/A*.tar.gz | tail -n +3 | xargs rm -rf
ls -1t /var/www/archive/B*.tar.gz | tail -n +3 | xargs rm -rf
ls -1t /var/www/archive/C*.tar.gz | tail -n +3 | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Протестировал скрипт. В общем он делает немного не то, допустим у меня есть 10 сборок, после выполнения остаются сборки 3.tgz,6.tgz,9.tgz. А мне нужно оставлять 8,9,10, а остальное удалять.